# It possible in Resteasy to extract the URI mapping to an external, dedicated file?

Tags: rest, resteasy

It possible in Resteasy to extract the URI mapping to an external, dedicated file?

Annotating classes and methods is quick and easy but I would like to have a file that maps the URIs to functions. Something like:

```
/teams/{team}/player/{player-id}  TeamResource.fetchPlayer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not currently supported as part of the JAX-RS specification, but I could see you being able to do this with byte code insertion at runtime using something like [javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist).

Basically you would add the @Path annotations to the your resource classes at runtime with the values loaded from your uri mapping file.  Once the annotations were added to the resource you would then inject them into Resteasy.